# Is there a C implementation for GNU ARM NEON intrinsics?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, simd, neon

I'm not looking for a portable SIMD implementation.

All I need is: a bit-accurate implementation. Performance doesn't matter very much as long as it's not extremely slow.

I want to use it for early stage developing and testing, so that I can compile and run on a host computer for the first 10+ iterations. Then cross-compile and fine tune performance on the ARM target.

I'm pretty used to this development cycle when I work with TI DSP like [described here](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/7/75/Host_intrinsics_overview.pdf) . I want to carry this on when I move to ARM NEON.

Is this already done, or do I need to invent the wheel?

Comment: I don't know of any portable implementation, except a VM like QEMU. Install a linux ARM distro into a VM and compile away. This is what I do at home.

Comment: @user1095108 Yes, that's a way to do it. But then I need to interface development tools like python or matlab with the emulated VM, rather than a C function compiled to a library. I gut feeling is that interfacing with VM is no easier than interfacing with the target board, so I lose most of the advantage of running it on the host.

Comment: I am also interested in a tool like this, have you invented one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intel has [a useful set of macros, `neon2sse.h`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/12/12/from-arm-neon-to-intel-mmxsse-automatic-porting-solution-tips-and-tricks) which translate NEON intrinsics to SSE. This enables you to build and test your C/C++ code with NEON intrinsics on an x86 platform.

Comment: Sure, but OP said portable way. You answer is x86 only.

Comment: @user1095108: well the question is not entirely clear - the OP says "I'm **not** looking for a portable SIMD implementation", but then goes on to say "All I need is: a portable and bit-accurate implementation". But given that x86 is pretty ubiquitous, and the OP seems to just want to be able to prototype/build/test in a hosted environment, then a generic x86 solution seems to fit the portability requirement (IMNVHO ;-)). The OP hasn't commented, but he has accepted the answer, so I assume it meets his needs.

Comment: I knew of these macros myself, but didn't answer because the question specifically says "portable". Maybe the question should be edited.

Comment: Yes, the question ideally needs to be clarified as to the OP's specific requirements. Having said that, it's probably off-topic, since it's asking for recommendations, so it may well get closed.

Comment: I edited it, but hopefully it will be closed, yes.